# Cassandra not started correctly

Tags: cassandra

I try to build Cassandra cluster with 3 nodes

On node 1 i've got a trouble when i try use cqlsh:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

In cassandra.yaml i dont't see strings with ip 127.0.0.1, i wrote there correct parametres (in my mind)

```
cluster_name: 'cassandra_cluster'
seeds: "node_public_ip_1,node_public_ip_2,node_public_ip_3"
listen_address: node_public_ip_1
rpc_adress: node_public_ip_1
```

in cassandra-topology.properties:

```
`# Cassandra Node IP=Data Center:Rack`
```

`node_public_ip_1=dc1:rac1`
`node_public_ip_2=dc1:rac1`
`node_public_ip_3=dc1:rac1`

What i do wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run cqlsh without specifying the host, it defaults to `localhost` (`127.0.0.1`). You need to specify the client IP address (`rpc_address`) of the node you want to connect to when running cqlsh.

Also, the standard recommendation for multi-homed servers is to use the private IP for internal cluster comms and the public IP for client connections. This means that in `cassandra.yaml` you would configure:

```
listen_address: private_ip
rpc_address: public_ip
```

Since the seeds are used for seeding cluster communication, you would also configure the seeds list with the nodes' private IP addresses.

Finally, if you're using the old `PropertyFileSnitch`, you should also configure `cassandra-topology.properties` with the nodes' private IP addresses.

However, PFS is really old and in almost all cases our recommendation is to use `GossipingPropertyFileSnitch` since it has all the benefits of being able to expand the cluster in the future without any downsides as I've explained in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/8887/.

It is also a lot simpler to manage GPFS since you only need to set a single node's DC and rack configuration in `cassandra-rackdc.properties` without having to reconfigure all the nodes whenever you add/remove nodes from the cluster.

When you do switch to GPFS, you should delete `cassandra-topology.properties`  on the nodes to prevent any gossip issues in the future as I've explained in this post -- https://community.datastax.com/questions/4621/. Cheers!

Comment: Great thanks for your answe, Erick!
i think i'm stupid, but i have issue:
I connect to node via ssh, which has public_ip1

And when i try use on this node
`cqlsh public_ip1`
i see:
`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'172.27.64.150': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('172.27.64.150', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})`

i removed `cassandra-topology.properties` from all nodes

Answer (score 0):

Try run the "nodetool status" and "nodetool describecluster" on both nodes of this cluster to identify the IP used by nodes.

and try connect passing the host/ip. like:

cqlsh <host> <port> -u <user> -p <password>

Comment: On node1 when i use "nodetool status" it's work correctly. I see correct ip-adress
On node2 and node3 when i use "nodetool status":
`nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.`





and when i use "nodetool describecluster":
`nodetool: Failed to connect to '127.0.0.1:7199' - ConnectException: 'Connection refused (Connection refused)'.`